# Trying to use getBoundingClientRect() on an element added programmatically returns width and height 0

Tags: javascript, svg, getboundingclientrect

I'm trying to get the `getBoundingClientRect()` of an `object` element that I just added to the `body`, but it returns `width` and `height` 0. Currently I fixed the issue adding an SVG to the html containing the same picture and set the visibility to hidden, then getting the width and height from that. The size of the object is a percentage of the window size so I have no way of knowing it in advance.

```
let bulletSVG = document.createElement("object");
bulletSVG.setAttribute("class", "bullet"); 
bulletSVG.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml"); 
bulletSVG.setAttribute("data", "imgs/bullet.svg");

document.body.appendChild(bulletSVG);

console.log(bulletSVG.getBoundingClientRect());
```

I'd rather not add an SVG to the body just to get the width and height. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My educated guess is that the browser doesn't know yet the size of the image since you're not waiting for the image to be fully loaded. I would do something like that:

```
const load = (obj) => 
  new Promise(resolve => obj.onload = resolve);

async function addSVG() {
  let bulletSVG = document.createElement("object");
  bulletSVG.setAttribute("class", "bullet"); 
  bulletSVG.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml"); 
  bulletSVG.setAttribute("data", "imgs/bullet.svg");

  document.body.appendChild(bulletSVG);

  await load(bulletSVG);

  console.log(bulletSVG.getBoundingClientRect());
}

addSVG();
```

**UPDATE**
If your browser doesn't support promises, and you can't / don't want use transpiler (such as Babel 7); you make it working using directly the event handler, although it won't be so elegant:

```
function addSVG() {
  let bulletSVG = document.createElement("object");
  bulletSVG.setAttribute("class", "bullet"); 
  bulletSVG.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml"); 
  bulletSVG.setAttribute("data", "imgs/bullet.svg");

  document.body.appendChild(bulletSVG);

  bulletSVG.onload = function() {
    console.log(bulletSVG.getBoundingClientRect());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to make this work on IE11, but it seems that promises are not supported.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement your solution.